# Trouble sending multiple notifications using APNS

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send multiple notifications using my PHP script. But after sending about 50 or so out of the 10k users, I get a broken pipe warning. I'm not sure whether that message is sent.
From various other posts, I learnt that it could be because of a invalid token. However, my feedback service returns no invalid tokens. (ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196) Tried this both in production mode and sandbox mode.

What other reasons could cause this invalid pipe issue?

My exact problem is explained here by someone else as well.

http://pastie.org/698787.txt

Answer (score 0):

Apple's servers will drop the connection as soon as there is something wrong in the stream of your push messages.

Be careful with mixing device tokens between sandbox and production modes. There's an article [here](http://www.programbles.com/2009/12/14/things-i-learned-integrating-with-apples-push-notification-service/) that describes the issue.

Also, have you tried using the enhanced notification format described in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)? The response might tell you what's wrong.